# Change border color of <input> when selected

Tags: html, css, next.js

I'm coding a login screen for a next.js app and when I select a  the color of the border becomes this white+blue mix.

[image]

I've tried the following

```
.input:focus {
  border: 5px solid #f23;
}
```

But it changes something else:

[image]

How can I change the color of the border?

```
<input type="text" className={styles.input} style={{ marginBottom: 10 }} autoComplete="off" autoCorrect="off" autoCapitalize="off" aria-required="true" spellCheck="false" placeholder="Email" ></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is likely an outline:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

Either make your `outline: none;` and use the `border` property or just restyle the outline:

```
.input:focus {
  outline: 5px solid #f23;
}
```